# libspotify API: what is the relationship among the availability of track, album, playlist, image etc.?

Tags: spotify

Track data needs to be ready in order to play the track. Does album have to be loaded in order to retrieve the album cover art image? Is it same for artist portrait?

I'm trying to retrieve album cover art image with album URI available. My plan was to get the album cover art image id from the album uri, and then get the image data from the image id. It looks like album cover art image id is not available if album is not loaded.

My question is - is it possible to get the cover image id without loading the whole album object (including all tracks)?

Thanks.

Comment: If the metadata of a track is loaded, and the album handler (sp_album*) is got from the track, do I still have to wait for the album information to be loaded in order to get the cover art image id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every single metadata object is separate from any associated metadata objects — when a track is loaded, it only knows the ID of its associated artist(s) and album. If you want the artist(s) and album as well, you need to load them separately. Metadata loading for an object is all or nothing — either it's loaded or it isn't.

With that in mind, you must wait for an album object to be loaded completely before you can get the cover ID for that album.

However, loading an album doesn't load all of its tracks (that's what `sp_ablumbrowse` is for). Loading the metadata for an album is actually very lightweight.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I still don't understand the relationship between album and albumbrowse. For example, I want to retrieve the cover ID of an album. I will use **sp_album_is_loaded** to check if an album is loaded. If it's loaded, retrieve the cover ID, and wait otherwise. But it seems the "wait" for album to be loaded doesn't work. Instead, I have to use albumbrowse call back. Does that mean using albumbrowse call back is the only way to wait for album metadata to be loaded?

Comment: `albumbrowse` gives artist, copyrights, reviews and tracks. You don't need it for covers. If the album isn't loaded, wait for the `metadata_updated` callback and try again.

Comment: oh, I thought metadata_updated callback is for track metadata only. What else is it for? artist? Is it the only way for track metadata then?

Comment: `metadata_updated` is for everything metadata-y — tracks, artists, albums, etc.

Comment: Is it for playlist and image as well? playlist and image have their own callbacks. And does **metadata_updated** callback happens only upon request - e.g. user calls **sp_link_as_album** (assume no any other changes)? Thanks.

Comment: what i tried to say is that how to make sure that the album is loaded when **metadata_updated** is called (assume no other changes etc.). If I still have to check sp_album_is_loaded, it would be simpler to use sp_albumbrowse callback instead. And if **metadata_updated** is shared by more than one items (e.g. album and playlist), it needs to find out which item is really updated.

Comment: Do it whichever way you feel is best. `metadata_updated` just means "some new metadata arrived" and can happen at any time. See the libSpotify documentation for details.